# Scanning a text file with Java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

The purpose is to print-out a list of names from a .txt file. The code I've used is below.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.util.Scanner;

import java.io.File;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;


public class FileScanner3 {

public static void main(String args []) throws FileNotFoundException {

    ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
    String inName;

    //Setup a scanner to read from a text file
    Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("namefile.txt").getAbsoluteFile());

    while (in.hasNextLine()) {
        inName = in.next();     
        //Use next() to read string
        names.add(inName);
    }

    //Tidy up by closing files
    in.close();

    //Print names ArrayList
    for(int i =0; i<names.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println((i + 1) + "\t" + names.get(i));
    }
}
}
```

The error that I get is this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException

at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)

at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)

at FileScanner3.main(FileScanner3.java:17)
```

If anyone is able to tell me what is wrong, that would be fantastic!

Edit: Spelling

Comment: Can you post the contents of the file?

Comment: The [Javadoc for next() method says](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29):

Throws: NoSuchElementException - if no more tokens are available

Comment: Never used Scanner, but reading the doc, it seems you'd get this if the file ended with whitespace and a line-end. There would be a  line (so `hasNextLine` returns true) but no token (so `next` would fail)

Comment: The contents of the file are as follows:
Jack

Ben

Ryan


Sam

Ted

Bill

Simon

Andrew

That's it. They are all on different lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without the text file, it is hard to guess, but I suppose there is a blank line at the end of the file. You could prevent this error by chaning the inner loop to

```
 while (in.hasNext()) {
        inName = in.next();     
        //Use next() to read string
        names.add(inName);
 }
```

I hope it helps.